# Free Video tutorials on Subfile programming

Tags: video, ibm-midrange

I have been searching for free video tutorials on subfile programming for quite a while now.

I have been going through Kevin Vandevers books and though they are quite good, I still feel a video tutorial that shows step - by - step on how to design a subfile using SDA and the associated RPG would really be helpful to cement the concepts in my head.

https://www.lab400.com/ provides training material for 995 dollars which is almost equal to 65000 INR , which is just a few thousands less than my Monthly salary! hence this is not affordable.

Having learned tons of other things like excel VBA, java etc through videos, there is an earnest yearning for something similar for Subfiles.

So if any of you are aware of any sources for this and could let me know, it would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Note that requests for tutorials are off-topic here, see the Help Centre.

Answer (score 1):

I "do" subfiles and the reference book i use you can get from Amazon ...

[https://www.amazon.com/Subfiles-Rpg-Programmers-Comprehensive-Guide/dp/1883884187/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1484930857&sr=8-2&keywords=subfiles+for+RPG](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1883884187)

I cant help with video, but books are nice resources. 
Good luck.

Comment: Sorry have to disagree here. This book might be good. But is it up to date?

Comment: Is the book, Subfiles for RPG Programmers, up to date?  My honest answer is I dont know that subfile processing has changed that much. If you are a green screen programmer and want to do subfiles in windows you make, that would be comprehensive chapter 3.  That book is fraught with example code... like full programs with DDS specs right along with it.

Comment: There may be some RPG4 processing that will look different in free form, but i would guess(emphasis on guess) that you'd still EXFMT for display or turn indicators on and off to clear a subfile with a WRITE function.